# Which of the following methods cause the string object referenced by s to be changed?

Tags: java, string

[image]1  - `s.concat()`

2  - `s.toUpperCase()`

3  - `s.replace()`

4  - `s.valueOf()`

Here none is not an option and people have scored 100% so i assumed that every operation is assigning back the return value to s.

I saw the code of all methods. All return `new string()`. But this answer is wrong as per [**techgig**](https://www.techgig.com/).

As per my understanding all 4 should cause object reference changed. but its wrong as per techgig.

For Quiz Question Follow Below Steps:-

- Visit [TechGig](https://www.techgig.com/)
- Log in into it
- Open practice tab
- Go to the java section
- Open Introduction Basic Level

Comment: `String` is immutable.

Comment: SO != quiz passing engine.

Comment: What do you think? What makes you think so?

Comment: not all of them. And i am not trying to pass any quiz. I studied the code of all methods. all return new string(). but this answer is wrong.

Comment: "And i am not trying to pass any quiz" != " this answer is wrong as per techgig."

Comment: If you studies please add explanation as well. And if you know the answer please post it here.

Comment: "all return new string()... but this answer is wrong" what makes you think so?

Comment: @raina77ow . I already scored 90%. and test is finished.

Comment: @Pshemo - I think all 4 should cause change of reference but this ans is wrong as per techgig. so now i am confused

Comment: @Goion Sorry for my poor skills of asking question. I am trying to find right answer. May be i am right. but i want to be sure about it.

Comment: If we have `String s = "abc";` and we will execute `s.toUpperCase();` what will be result of `System.out.println(s);`?

Comment: Can you insert the image of question + the reason it gave why your answer is wrong. The link you gave isn't going to the specific question you asked. If someone wants to check they have to sign up and dig through quizzes to find out.

Comment: @Pshemo  abc is the answer.

Comment: None of those methods change the String referenced by `s`, because Strings cannot be changed.   All you can do is create a _new_ String, and assign it to the same variable.

Comment: @SSP Do you understand why `abc` is the printed? If you call `System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());` you would see `ABC` but as you already see value of `s` didn't change (it still holds reference to `abc` object). It happens because simply *returning* reference to *new String* doesn't mean original reference will nor should change. To change it we would need to explicitly write `s = s.toUpperCase();`.

Answer (score 1):

None of this method change the String object referred by `s`, because `String` object is immutable. So whatever function you perform it creates a new `String` object, which you can assign to some other reference or to `s` itself. When you will be assigning this newly created object to `s`, then `s` reference will be pointing to this new Object.

For example:

```
String s  = "hello";
//Now perform all four operation one by one
s.concat("world");
s.toUpperCase();
s.replcae("l", "m");
s.valueOf(true);

System.out.println(s);
```

Even after all of these operations the output will be : **hello**

Comment: Here none is not an option and people have scored 100% so i assumed that every operation is assigning back the return value to s.

Comment: Shouldn't `s.valueOf(true)` be accessed in a static way? e.g `String.valueOf(true)`?

Comment: Yes totally agreed, it not recommended to call  static method using object, although it's correct syntatically. But I have kept it this way only not to divert from main point of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

All options aside `s.toUpperCase()` will throw compile errors, because they need arguments. Maybe the question wanted you to notice that and mark that option. Of course, like many people noticed, `String` is immutable, so it's not possible change one `String` object, but you can change `s` variable to have another `String` reference and since there is no `s = new String();` anywhere happening, probably this question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

- As per my knowledge and research, The right answer to your question is `s.concat()` and `s.toUpperCase()`. As you said that many programmers score 100% so you can try this. You'll also get a 100% score. Also, I got a 100% score on the quiz.
- The string literal with the same content share storage in a common pool, Java's String is designed to be immutable. Let's for example
  `String s1 = "Java"`
  `String s2 = "Java"`
- Both `s1` and `s2` pointing the same memory space i.e One String is constructed, it's content can't be modified. Otherwise, Other String reference sharing the same storage location will be affected.
- Methods such as toUpperCase() might appear to modify the contents of a String object. In fact, a completely new String object is created and returned to the caller. The original String object will be deallocated, once there are no more references, and subsequently garbage-collected.
- Your question was asked in many quizzes I found some pages where the answer is given but no explanation is there. You can check the answer on [this](https://javaavaj.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/string-handling-question/) and [this](http://3s-technologies.com/index_files/JavaQApart4.htm) website.

**Reference** : [Java String Tutorial](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html)